# Can I use sage tea as a herb while cooking

Tags: tea, herbs

I have a bag of loose sage tea, that I do not use for tea. I was wondering whether or not I could use these leaves in my dishes. At first sight, it seems all sage.

Is there a way to know if it is indeed all sage and without any tea leaves? There are no ingredients listed on the bag.
Would it be dangerous to cook with, if there was tea in it? My guess is that it would be fine, but might give a nasty flavor.

Answer (score 2):

Without a list of ingredients there's no way to know what else is in your sage tea, or what flavors it will impart to a dish.

If the tea you get from the bag is pleasant then the flavor it imparts to the food should also be good, although sage is a very powerful herb and a whole tea bag of it would likely be far too much.

My view on this is that while you don't want to waste food you also don't want to ruin it, and the global ecology is not going to collapse because you get rid of a sage tea bag. If you really want to use it rip it open and try it on a small dish first and see what results you get.

Answer (score 2):

I cook with tea all the time. Adding loose leaves works fine if you're comfortable with the flavor and the technique, but if you're not, just brew some and use the tea in place of water...This has the added benefit that you can be sure of the final flavor before you add it to the dish.